# Tag not found [ConTeXt]

Tags: support, tagging

I usually search for questions, by using the tag of whatever I want to look for. This time around, after typing `ConTeXt`, no tag was found. The message on the right corner read: `0 questions tagged {context}`

So I said, alright, it seems is a problem with the system, but then I searched for other tags, and no problem whatsoever appeared. Is this the default? I don't recall running into the same problem before.

It's funny though, that it says that the tag was searched for in the featured tab, when this is not the case.

[image]

Comment: Because you are searching for `featured` Q's which are `context` tagged that are `zero` in number, rather you should be searching for [ConTeXt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) with `newest` Q tab

Comment: it remembers the `Frequent` tab and you might need to switch the tab to `newest` henceforth you can see **You are on the Featured Tab**

Comment: @texenthusiast it's funny this is happening in firefox only

Comment: @texenthusiast You are right, it remembers the `frequent` tab, instead of `newest`. It happens only in firefox though.

Comment: now everything works regardless of the tab

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-issue that seems to have resolved itself.

Comment: @Werner fine if it's closed.

Comment: @Werner I’m not sure if this question must be closed on meta. It’s a support question that’s basically based on a misunderstanding of a slightly confusing aspect of the system. It’d keep it open since other users might run into the same problem, and perhaps try to edit it to be even more helpful and findable. **Voting to reopen**

Comment: @doncherry Maybe I haven't got up well today, but even seeing the (deleted) answer, I don't understand what the issue was :-/ Therefore in the current form, the question doesn't seem to me to be any useful...

Comment: @tohecz it was my fault. I can't fully understand the wiki alike design behind this site. It's funny though, it has happened to me before, and this time around, perhaps I wanted to find something wrong or perhaps the new redesign of the site influenced my decision to post a question. I don't want to excuse myself by adding this though, but to me it has not been the most intuitive friendly interface either. Hopefully one day I can get around without making the same mistake

Comment: @doed I sort to agree with doncherry that the question might be good, but in current state it's completely unclear what is it about. So for me, unless you decide to make it clearer, I don't see a reason for re-opening. --- --- And btw, I think that every single person here stumbled across a problem with using some of the site's features, so you need not be sorry ;)

Comment: In any case this seems to be a duplicate of http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3820/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann you are correct! It is self-explanatory when you think about it, if there was only a better way to distinguish the tabs. I have no tags in the profile to follow, and probably I should have done so, since perhaps that should have resolved the issue, and I would not have been in the predicament to question whether something was wrong with the site.